# How to transform a table into a table of trends

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of customers. Every time they place an order, it can be a little different.

My list of orders by customer looks something like this:

[image: sample customer orders]

Although all the orders are different, there is a trend by customer for each field.

So every time there is an order from a specific customer, I make an analysis about the trend for that customer. (My analysis is done field by field and not about each order as a group of fields.)

I’m currently using formula `=INDEX(C2:C164; MODE(MATCH(C2:C164; C2:C164; 0)))`  and my analysis looks like this:

[image: analysis]

But this formula only allows me to analyze customer by customer. How can I make this analysis for all the customers at the same time? What I would like to do is to create an overall table for all the customers from the data of the initial table.

The idea is to transform the initial table into a table of trends by customer. That is a table of the predominant patterns for each customer, by field (the most frequent choice by column, by customer).

Is this possible?

Comment: I’m working with Excel 97-2003 Workbook, but I can use Macro-Enabled if useful. I also might use google-sheets if necessary.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's the desired result?Unclear: `But this formula only allows me to analyze customer by customer. How can I make this analysis for all the customers at the same time?`

Comment: The desired result is a table of trends by customer. That is a table of the predominant patterns for each customer, by field (the most frequent choice by column, by customer). A table like the second print in the question.

Comment: So,What's wrong with the second print's formula?

Comment: I'm doing line by line manually, with formula =INDEX(C2:C164; MODE(MATCH(C2:C164; C2:C164; 0))). I want to do all the lines at the same time, that is to create a table from the original table.

Comment: So,You don't want to `drag fill` the formula? Or Is the formula not drag-fillable?  Is it something else?

Comment: The formula is not drag-fillable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77358/discussion-between-ceu-melo-and-i-i).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets)

- First screenshot table: A1:F15
- Second table: A21:E24

B22(for Black):

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FILTER(C$2:C$15,$A$2:$A$15=$A22),"Select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 order by count(Col1) desc",0),2,1)
```

- FILTER to filter out Colors for the customer in (A22).
- QUERY to sort descending by COUNT.
- INDEX to choose the top Color.

Comment: Note: Will Not Work in Excel. Try SuperUser or StackOverflow if you want excel-vba. However,Using Excel only formulas,B22: `=ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(C$2:C$15,MATCH(MAX(IF($A22=$A$2:$A$15,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$15&C$2:C$15,$A$2:$A$15&C$2:C$15))),IF($A22=$A$2:$A$15,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$15&C$2:C$15,$A$2:$A$15&C$2:C$15)),0),1))` CSE instead of arrayformula in excel

Comment: Lemme know if it works in Excel.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not working, the excel returns error in formula :( I've tried to understand/solve, but with no success :'( can you please re-check? [I've replaced all "," by ";"] What do you mean with "CSE instead of arrayformula in excel"?

Comment: @Ceu Hi.. Try the "excel formula" in gSheets. It works. It might help in understanding.  CSE means  CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER .It's a array formula and hence should be entered as such with CSE in excel. I tried dummifying it for excel more: `=INDEX(C$2:C$15,MATCH(MAX(IF($A22=$A$2:$A$15,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$15&C$2:C$15,$A$2:$A$15&C$2:C$15),""),0),IF($A22=$A$2:$A$15,COUNTIF($A$2:$A$15&C$2:C$15,$A$2:$A$15&C$2:C$15),""),0),1)`  Enter with CSE.

Comment: Dear I'-'I, just pasted the formula in gSheets and it worked fine!!! Thank you very much!!! You have no idea how much this will improve my life :D

Comment: @Ceu So,You're ditching excel? If you're using gSheets,Prefer the original Filter/query combo(It'll be much faster, IMO than  COUNTIF/CONCAT). Cheers.